# Outer automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need help to answer the following problem:

> Let $F$ be a field and $n\ge 2$.
>
> Define $\phi:GL(n,F)\to GL(n,F)$ by $\phi(g)=(g^{-1})^T$, where $T$ denotes the transpose.
>
> Suppose that $F$ has at least four elements. Show that $\phi$ is an outer automorphism of $GL(n,F)$.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hint: Consider the center of the group. What happens to the center under an inner automorphism?

Comment: i didn't understand the answer can you please explain more. Thanks

Comment: Which part of the answer at the duplicate you do not understand? That any element of the center must be fixed, for an inner automorphism? That $\phi$ above does not fix it?

Comment: That $ϕ$ above does not fix it?

Comment: Mona, do you know what the center of $GL(n,F)$ is?

Comment: the centre of $\operatorname{GL}(n,F)$ is $\lbrace\lambda I\mid λ ∈ F^∗\rbrace$. and then what to do?

Comment: Ok. What is $((\lambda I)^{-1})^T$? Compare with $A(\lambda I)A^{-1}$ for some arbitrary $A\in GL(n,F)$.

Comment: $((\lambda I)^{-1})^T=\frac{1}{\lambda}I$ and $A(\lambda I)A^{-1}
=\lambda I$ then $((\lambda I)^{-1})^T$ is different from $A(\lambda I)A^{-1}$ for all $\lambda\in F\backslash\left\{1_F,-1_F\right\}$. and how does that answer the quetion?

Comment: Mona, if $F$ has at least four elements, then there exists $\lambda\in F\setminus\{\pm1_F,0_F\}$.